# strcmp() and signed / unsigned chars

Tags: c, standards

I am confused by strcmp(), or rather, how it is defined by the standard. Consider comparing two strings where one contains characters outside the ASCII-7 range (0-127).

The C standard defines:

> **int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);**
>
> The strcmp function compares the string pointed to by s1 to the string
>   pointed to by s2.
>
> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
>   less than zero, accordingly as the
>   string pointed to by s1 is greater
>   than, equal to, or less than the
>   string pointed to by s2.

The parameters are **`char *`**. Not **`unsigned char *`**. There is no notion that "comparison should be done as `unsigned`".

But all the standard libraries I checked consider the "high" character to be just that, *higher* in value than the ASCII-7 characters.

I understand this is useful and the expected behaviour. I don't want to say the existing implementations are wrong or something. I just want to know, **which part in the standard specs have I missed**?

```
int strcmp_default( const char * s1, const char * s2 )
{
    while ( ( *s1 ) && ( *s1 == *s2 ) )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }
    return ( *s1 - *s2 );
}

int strcmp_unsigned( const char * s1, const char *s2 )
{
    unsigned char * p1 = (unsigned char *)s1;
    unsigned char * p2 = (unsigned char *)s2;

    while ( ( *p1 ) && ( *p1 == *p2 ) )
    {
        ++p1;
        ++p2;
    }
    return ( *p1 - *p2 );
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x1[] = "abc";
    char x2[] = "abü";
    printf( "%d\n", strcmp_default( x1, x2 ) );
    printf( "%d\n", strcmp_unsigned( x1, x2 ) );
    printf( "%d\n", strcmp( x1, x2 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
103
-153
-153
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

7.21.4/1 (C99), emphasis is mine:

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions memcmp, strcmp,
>   and strncmp is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first
>   pair of characters (**both interpreted as unsigned char**) that differ in the objects being
>   compared.

There is something similar in C90.

Note that strcoll() may be more adapted than strcmp() especially if you have character outside the basic character set.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly the kind of answer I've been looking for. Thanks!