# Strncmp implementation

Tags: c, string, compare

I have the following implementation of strncmp function with a test driver, however  that does`t compile.

I`m also not sure if the logic is correct. Here is the error message from my compiler:

> warning: control may reach end of non-void function
>         [-Wreturn-type]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#undef strncmp

int strncmp(const char *s, const char *t, size_t num)
{
    for ( ; num >0;  s++, t++, num--)
        if (*s == 0)
            return 0;

    if (*s == *t) {
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
    else if (*s != *t)
        return *s - *t;  
}

 int main ()
 {
   char str[][5] = { "R2D2" , "C3PO" , "R2A6" };
   int n;
   puts ("Looking for R2 astromech droids...");
   for (n=0 ; n<3 ; n++)
     if (strncmp (str[n],"R2xx",2) == 0)
     {
       printf ("found %s\n",str[n]);
     }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There are at least three to four bugs in your implementation. Why don't you head over to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to let people take your code apart line by line?

Comment: No, @NikolaiRuhe, CodeReview is for only working code. SO is for broken code.

Comment: @ARedHerring Not sure about CodeReview but SO does not seem to be a good fit either (see help section about "why isn't this code working?"-type of questions).

Comment: Just because it is off-topic on SO does **not** mean it is on-topic at CR. If it is off-topic here, vote to close, but please read our help section before suggesting a migration, otherwise the user will just be left disappointed on two fronts and that helps no-one.

Comment: Please please please please: **Always** put braces (`{ }`) around the body of `if` / `else` / `for` / `while`. This is among the top reasons for errors created by careless coding.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from errors mentioned by others, [you are supposed to compare the characters as `unsigned char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356741). This gets important once you go beyond ASCII-7, **your results will be wrong** if you don't.

The following is my own (tested) implementation (from my original work on [PDCLib](http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de/), which is [CC0 licensed](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)).

```
int strncmp( const char * s1, const char * s2, size_t n )
{
    while ( n && *s1 && ( *s1 == *s2 ) )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
        --n;
    }
    if ( n == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ( *(unsigned char *)s1 - *(unsigned char *)s2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `n && *s1 ...` to avoid accessing memory that it should not.

Comment: @chux: That could only be an issue if `s1` did not point at a valid string, which would be UB to begin with (7.1.4 Use of library functions / 7.21.1 String function conventions (2)). But yes, putting `n` first would be more robust. My design decision back then was to aim for maximum performance without making the code "doing tricks", and I considered `s1` being exhausted to be more likely than `n` running to zero. Mileage may vary.

Comment: `strncmp` is under `Comparison functions` along with `memcmp()`.  `s1` need not point to a valid string (null character terminated). It is not UB to pass an invalid _string_ pointer.  Only a valid pointer to an array of characters is needed - thus the need to test `n` first.

Comment: `*(unsigned char *)s1 - *(unsigned char *)s2` is better than `s1 - s2`.  On rare platforms where the range of `unsigned char` is the same as `int/unsigned`,  better to do `(*(unsigned char *)s1 > *(unsigned char *)s2) - (*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2)` to avoid overflow.  Still like this answer the best.

Comment: @chux: By virtue of being a valid pointer to an (existing) array, `*s1` is well-behaved in all cases. ;-)

Comment: Consider `char s1[4] = {1,2,3,4}; strncmp(s1, s2, sizeof s1)`.  The  original answer accessed `s1[4]` which is beyond `s1[]` and UB.  `s1` as initially passed can have `*s1` as well-behaved, but incrementing _and_ accessing it once too far is the concern of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

`control may reach end of non-void function`

The last iteration of a non-void function must be a return. (your function return an int)

In some cases your code will not use a return. You need one so try to find where ;).

Comment: Ok, what should it return then?

Comment: "return *s - *t;" This will return an int so it is good.
Look at the comment from kaitian. If you don't get in the else, you don't return anything, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

See your code:

```
 for ( ; num >0;  s++, t++, num--)



      if (*s == 0)
          return 0;

      if (*s == *t) {
          ++s;
          ++t;
      }

       else if (*s != *t)
          return *s - *t;
```

1. Actually, your code is more like this:

   ```
   for ( ; num >0;  s++, t++, num--) {
         if (*s == 0)
             return 0;
   }

     if (*s == *t) {
         ++s;
         ++t;
     }

      else if (*s != *t)
         return *s - *t;
   ```
2. you have two "`s++; p++"`

See [this](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strncmp) and [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/ppc.subproj/strncmp.c) For more details

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at it piece by piece

```
for ( ; num >0;  s++, t++, num--)
    if (*s == 0)
        return 0;
```

The loop above increments s and t until num is 0 or until s points to 0, in which case you return 0.  If num > strlen(s) you always return 0.

Now we have finished the loop.  Let's see what happens next...

```
if (*s == *t) {
    ++s;
    ++t;
}
else if (*s != *t)
    return *s - *t;
```

If s and t both point to characters with the same value, they are both incremented, otherwise you return the difference of what they point to.  Notice, if they are equal you never explicitly return a value. This is the cause of the compiler error.

Then you need to fix the algorithm, which is currently hopelessly wrong.